# css multiple selector last one doesn't work

Tags: css, input, css-selectors

I want to use some CSS code with single line, I dont know why but somehow last element wont affected by my css code, why it is that?

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atahta/n1dp3a48/8/)

CSS:

```
 #ask-us input[type=email], 
input[type=text]{
  color: #121111; 
  border: 3px solid #ccc; 
  width: 171px;
  }
```

HTML:

```
    <p><!--EMAIL-->
    <input type="email" name="postEmail" id="postEmail" class="required" value="value" /><br />
    </p>
</form><!--end form-->
```

Answer (score 2):

The selector `#ask-us input[type=email]` says that the input of type email has to be within an element with the id `ask-us`. Which it apparently isn't.

Answer (score 1):

as [Philipp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6724033/philipp) said, just try

```css
input[type=email], input[type=text]{
  color: #121111; 
  border: 3px solid #ccc; 
  width: 171px;
}
```